# Bosh init gives error, on openstack, while creating bosh VM through script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openstack, cf-bosh

I have created an OpenStack environemt and I want to deploy BOSH, after which I will be deploying CloudFoundry on that VM for our office's Test environment. I am following these links as guides:

- [guide for Configuring the OpenStack Icehouse on Ubuntu LTS 14.04](http://www.stackgeek.com/guides/gettingstarted.html)
- [guides for BOSH](http://bosh.io/docs/init-openstack.html#prepare-openstack)

After I have confiugured the script according to my environment, I ran the script and got the following errors:

```
Error:
    Started deploying
      Creating VM for instance 'bosh/0' from stemcell '20e80643-76a0-4b28-8993-ceafd1ecfdaf'... Failed (00:00:04)
      Failed deploying (00:00:04)

    Stopping registry... Finished (00:00:00)

Command 'deploy' failed:
    Deploying:
        Creating instance 'bosh/0':
            Creating VM:
                Creating vm with stemcell cid '20e80643-76a0-4b28-8993-ceafd1ecfdaf':
            CPI 'create_vm' method responded with error: CmdError{"type":"Unknown","message":"Expected([200, 202]) \u003c=\u003e Actual(404 Not         Found)\nexcon.error.response\n  :body          =\u003e \"{\\\"itemNotFound\\\": {\\\"message\\\": \\\"The resource could not be found.\\\",         \\\"code\\\": 404}}\"\n  :headers       =\u003e {\n    \"Content-Length\"       =\u003e \"78\"\n    \"Content-Type\"         =\u003e \"applic        ation/json; charset=UTF-8\"\n    \"Date\"                 =\u003e \"Mon, 01 Jun 2015 07:59:11 GMT\"\n    \"X-Compute-Request-Id\" =\u003e \"r        eq-88aa57cd-b29f-49c0-ba77-a75292451367\"\n  }\n  :local_address =\u003e \"10.110.82.11\"\n  :local_port    =\u003e 52722\n  :reason_phrase =        \u003e \"Not Found\"\n  :remote_ip     =\u003e \"10.110.82.11\"\n  :status        =\u003e 404\n","ok_to_retry":false}
```

(Note: The script mentioned in above BOSH link referred to Stemcell 2950 but I have replaced it with the latest one i.e 2977)

Also, I am sort of new to the Linux, Openstack and cloud foundry so I apologize if it takes some time for me to understand and provide you with more diagnostic details.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the version of OpenStack you are using does not support [neutron networking](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/) used by the BOSH OpenStack CPI v28+ , so you can try enabling Nova-Networking in the BOSH cloud config properties use the older nova networking api.

```
properties:
  openstack: &openstack
    use_nova_networking: true
```

See http://bosh.io/docs/openstack-nova-networking.html for details.

Similar error found/addressed in https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-openstack-cpi-release/issues/59